# Series about being that could change sex and age - "The Morph*"

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to remember information about a series of three books I read in the early 1980's (first book could have been published in the 1970's). The book featured a character who was a scientific creation of some sort. It was (initially, I believe) an assassin, and had the ultimate getaway scheme; with effort, it could change its body, becoming about 10 years younger and switching sex. It changed 4 or 5 times in the first book, coming down from a senior citizen to someone in their teens or twenties; in the second and third books, it changed once per book (by the last book, it was a child or a young teenager).

The first book was title something like "The Morph..." where whatever the word was that started with "Morph" was this creature. No recollection of the author's name, or the titles of the other two books.

I think the cover of the first book was predominantly yellow, with black silhouettes representing the character at the four ages seen in the book, and a black title. And/or, the book might have been published by DAW (all their books at the time had yellow spines with black letters).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

M.A. Fosters [Transformer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M._A._Foster#Transformer) triology novels:

1. The Morphodite (1981)
2. Transformer (1983)
3. Preserver (1985)

Available from [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0756403561) with different covers.

The first two have the original images:

[image: Transformer Trilogy]

Answer (score 4):

This is "The Morphodite" by M.A. Foster.

https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?44374

http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2027620.The_Morphodite

> Their world was ultra-conservative, isolated, opposed to change. Their secret police had tried many means to keep it that way. Now they had contrived their cleverest secret weapon. This was a genetically-patterned, laboratory-raised human genius, the Morphodite.
>
> The Morphodite needed no computers to detect the key to any conspiracy -- the know-how was structured into his/her brain. The Morphodite needed no assistance to make a foolproof escape after such an assassination. The know-how was built into his/her body.

The image below matches your description almost perfectly, right down to the DAW publisher.

[image]